# Swagger + Springdoc OpenAPI + Spring Boot, how to secure the API definition endpoint

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, springdoc, springdoc-openapi-ui

Using Swagger UI from **Springdoc OpenAPI 1.5.11** in a **Spring Boot 2.5.3 web application** that exposes a REST API.

The REST API is secured using a bearer provided JWT token.

I successfully configured Springdoc to display the "Authorize" button with bearer authorization, where users can type a valid JWT token, and use that token when calling the REST API.

Hence, **using** the REST API is properly secured.

But **viewing** the REST API (endpoints, methods, input and output data structures, etc) **must also be secured**. This means that the API definition endpoint (the one defined by "springdoc.api-docs.path") called by Swagger UI should also use the token.

So far, I could not make Swagger UI use token to fetch the API definition, see snapshot.

[image: Swagger UI fails loading a secured API definition]

Is this possible ?

Comment: You can implement a request interceptor for the openapi endpoint alone. More details [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70487379/9269177)