# Swagger - Authorize request to url with documentation

Tags: spring-boot, swagger, openapi, springdoc

I am wondering whether there is an option in Swagger to authorize request to url containing external documentation.

I have the following configuration, what I am interested in is `urls[1]` part

```json
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[0].url=/v3/api-docs
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[0].name=default
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[1].url=https://asdasd.blob.core.windows.net/my-api/docs.spec
springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[1].name=additional
```

I am able to access the docs from the server (curl directly from the machine) however from the Swagger (so the browser) I can't. I am wondering if there is an option to add eg. `Authorization Bearer xxxx` to this request or actually make server issue the request, not the client.

To clarify - **I want to fetch second file with OpenAPI definition from the remote server** so I am talking about this:
[image]

Not the `Authorize` part
[image]

---

Solution I implemented:

What Helen pointed out would work - intercepting the request and adding the headers - however unfortunately in my case there was also an issue connected to firewall settings of a storage. Only traffic coming from the server, not the client (browser) was passing through so I:

1. Set the url to something in my domain 
   `springdoc.swagger-ui.urls[1].url=v3/api-docs/additional`
2. Specified another property for the url to the remote host 
   `mydomain.swagger-ui.additionalDocsUrl=...`
3. Implemented a custom controller handing that url - it fetches json from the remote as a server, instead of a client so firewall passes that request through

```java
@Hidden
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/v3/api-docs/additional")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class AdditionalOpenApiController {

    @Value("${mydomain.swagger-ui.additionalDocsUrl}")
    private String additionalDocsUrl;

    @Cacheable(value = "ADDITIONAL_API_DOCS", unless = "#result != null")
    @GetMapping(produces = "application/json")
    public String getAdditionalDocs() {
        // in my case remote produces application/octet-stream so it needs to be byte[]
        return Optional.ofNullable(new RestTemplate().getForObject(additionalDocsUrl, byte[].class)) 
                .map(String::new)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new ResourceNotFoundException("Cannot load Additional OpenAPI from storage"));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question, but you can add any authentication for separated requests, based on the [documentation](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/authentication/).

Comment: I clarified the question.

Comment: You need to add a [`requestInterceptor`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46892528/113116) to your Swagger UI configuration. The `requestInterceptor` can be used to mutate outgoing requests, e.g. add auth headers to the spec fetch request. I'm not sure how to do configure the `requestInterceptor` in Springdoc though.

Answer (score 1):

This can be achieved only programmatically.

- First: Implement your own `requestInterceptor` : See on [AbstractSwaggerIndexTransformer](https://github.com/springdoc/springdoc-openapi/blob/master/springdoc-openapi-common/src/main/java/org/springdoc/ui/AbstractSwaggerIndexTransformer.java) samples for implementing your request programmatically (for example addCSRF method).
- Second Implement your own `MySwaggerIndexPageTransformer` and define it as a spring bean and it will be loaded instead of the springdoc `SwaggerIndexPageTransformer`.
  [image]

Comment: Link is broken :-(